# Creating a conditional Many to Many relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

It seems easy but I still can't figure out how to implement it.

Trying to create a Many to Many conditional relations (not sure if it's the correct way to name it!) between three models:

```py
Class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


Class Article(models.Model):
    article_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


Class Portfolio(models.Model):
    KINDS = [('B', 'Book'), ('A', 'Article')]
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    kind = models.models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=KINDS)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Recommendation')


Class Recommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Each User (from the Django User module) can have multiple recommendations of portfolios. Each Portfolio is a group of books and articles recommended on a specific date.

Comment: I do not see what exactly you are trying to achieve. Could you describe what is an expected result ?

Comment: The portfolio is an aggregated table consisting of either a book or an article. I'm going to run different functions on each row depending on the type of the record.

Comment: Why do you need Portfolio model then ? You can just run different functions for Book model and different functions for Article model. If you really want to use Portfolio model you can add a choice field to your model and set its value when creating object. `model_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[('book', 'book'), ('article', 'article'')])`

Comment: @MehdiZare are you getting any errors? What are you looking for?

Comment: The portfolio is a 'through' model for a ManyToMany relation. I need this to link those tables. Let me update the question with more details to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would skip the Portfolio Model and just implement it this way:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Article(models.Model):
    article_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Recommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(book__isnull=True, article__isnull=False) | Q(book__isnull=False, article__isnull=True),
                name='only_book_or_article'
            )
        ]
```

you could skip the constrains but than you risk that your data is inconsistent

Comment: Thank you @Allamanda Weitgereist, It works just perfect. I just have a quick follow up on the Portfolio model. The main purpose was to be able to have a group of recommendation for a specific date from a specific user. Is there a workaround to achieve that with this implementation? [ A user can recommend a bunch of books or articles on a specific date]

Comment: you would have to change the article and book variable in the Recommendation model to a Many to many field. Than you would have to edit the constraint so that the model behaves as you wish. (can there be articles and books in one recommendation? )

Comment: Yes, recommendation can be of both types.